# $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(c,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2y)}{x^2-y^2} = 0$ when $c \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove by definition that, for $c \neq 0$,

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(c,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2y)}{x^2-y^2} = 0$$

I started this way:

$$\bigg|\frac{\sin(x^2y)}{x^2-y^2}\bigg|= \frac{|\sin(x^2y)|}{|x^2-y^2|} \stackrel{\text{$|\sin(\alpha)| \leq \alpha $}}{\leq} \frac{|x^2y|}{|x^2-y^2|} \stackrel{\text{AM-GM inequality}}{\leq}  \frac{x(x + y)}{4(x - y)}$$

But I'm totally stuck and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Using AM-GM inequality is a bad idea. Keep $y$ in the numerator. Use the fact that $|\frac {x^{2}} {|x^{2}-y^{2}|}| \leq \frac {x^{2}} {x^{2}-y^{2}}$ for $|y| <|x|$.Can you proceed from here? [You can use : $|x| \geq |c|-|x-c|$].

Comment: I don't get it. For $x=1, y=2$ your first inequality fails.

Comment: The inequality holds if $y$ is close to $0$ and $x$ is close to $c$. I should have specified that that I am using the inequality when $|y| <|x|$

Comment: @Deep_Television  $|x^{2}-y^{2}| \geq x^{2}-y^{2}$. we can write  $(|x^{2}-y^{2}|)^{-1} \leq (x^{2}-y^{2})^{-1}$ provided $x^{2}-y^{2}$ is positive.